# How to mention not of hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') in spring security taglib

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, taglib

How would I write following condition using spring security taglib?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<sec:authorize access="not of hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
   <div> show these for only non admins </div>
</sec:authorize>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
<sec:authorize access="!hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
   <div> show these for only non admins </div>
</sec:authorize>
```

Comment: Does not working on Controller/Mapped level: @PreAuthorize("!hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"). Any idea?