# In Spring Security how to handle NOT hasAuthority

Tags: spring-security

Using Spring Security we use **hasAuthority** to conditionally execute code or conditionally display parts of page in jsp.

eg:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_TELLER')")
public Account post(Account account, double amount);
}
```

or (in jsp)

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAuthority('TAG_SAVE')">
 .... content to display / evaluate
</sec:authorize>
```

I wanted to know how to handle a case when you want to show / execute something when not having Authority.

may something like

**doesNotHaveAuthority('TAG_SAVE')**

I am pretty sure, this is not an out of the blue use-case.
Has anyone handle this in any way?

Comment: Have you tried `!hasAuthority`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311104/how-to-mention-not-of-hasrolerole-admin-in-spring-security-taglib

Comment: Thanks Collin D, I got it working with !hasAuthority

Answer (score 4):

Actually found that this can use EL.
So Using a ! sign works.

So I got it work like this:

```
<sec:authorize access="!hasAuthority('TAG_SAVE')">
 .... content to display / evaluate when the Authority is not present
</sec:authorize>
```